# QT: how to create a new button when signal is emitted

Tags: c++, qt, signals, slot, qpushbutton

I want to create a `SLOT()` that creates a QPushButton (or a QLineEdit) widget on my Gui (on the same frame) whenever a `SIGNAL(clicked())` is emitted from a specific PushButton on my Gui. for example: when I press on "exit" a new "thanks" button appears on the same frame.

so, how do I create a new PushButton using c++ code and not the Qt-GUI tools ?

Comment: You may have the button already created, invisible and set it visible when some event occurs...

Comment: Have a look at the `ui_*.h`-files generated by Qt. You'll see how that magic Qt-GUI stuff is translated to code.

Comment: Create an object of QPushButton class in the handler for the "exit" button. And assign a new slot for that new button using connect().

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Of course, you can create widgets such as buttons without WYSIWYG tools (e.g. QtDesinger)

Write this code inside the slot of "exit" button:

```
void ThisWindowClass::exitClicked()
{
  // ...
  QPushButton *thanksButton = new QPushButton(this /*parent widget*/);
  connect(thanksButton, SIGNAL(clicked(bool)), this, SLOT(thanksClicked(bool)));
  // ...
}
```

And you must have a slot method named `thanksClicked`:

```
void ThisWindowClass::thanksClicked(bool checked)
{
 // Do something
}
```